# Java in-memory cache with subcaches for each client

Tags: java, caching

I have a ConcurrentMap which is my in-memory cache/database for my web app.
There I have stored my entity with the id as key.
This is how my entity basically looks like.

```
public class MyEntity {
     private int id;
     private String name;
     private Date start;
     private Date end;
     ...
}
```

Now I have multiple Users which requests different data from my map.
User1 has a filter for the start date. So for example he only gets item 1, 2, and 3 of my map. User2 has also a filter and only gets item 2, 3, 4, 5 of the map.
So they only get a part of the complete map. I am doing the filtering on my server because the map is to big to send the complete map and I need to check other attributes.

My problem now is that the entries in the map can be updated / removed / added from some other API calls and I want to live update the entries on the user side.

For now I am sending a notification to the users that the map has been updated and then every user loads the complete data which the user needs.
For example item 8 has been updated. User1 gets a notification and loads item 1, 2, 3 again even if the update was only on item 8. So in this case it would be unnecessary to update for User1 because he doesnt need item 8.

Now i am searching for a good solution so that the User only receives the necessary updates.

One way I was thinking about was to store temporarily all items id which the user requested. So on an update notification I can check if the item updated is in the list and then send the updated item to the user only if it is in the users list.
But I am concerning the memory usage that this will create in case I have a lot of users and the user list with the item ids can be very big too.

What would be a good solution to send only the added / updated / removed item to the user and only if the user needs that item?
So something like observing only a part of the base map (cache) but with a notification for every action like adding, updating and removing item.

Answer (score 0):

Basically there is no "Silver Bullet". A possible solution depends on the usage patterns, your resources and requirements.

Questions to ask:

- How big is the total dataset, now and in the future?
- How big is the displayed dataset?
- How many users with searches?
- Is it a business application with a closed user group or a public web application that needs to scale?
- What is the update frequency and what kind of updates are common?
- How many different search patterns are present?

The biggest question of all:

*Is it really needed?*

Looking at a bunch of search interfaces, the user expects an update only when there is an interaction. If it is similar to a search, then the users will not expect an instant update. An instant update can be useful and "innovative", but you do spend a lot of engineering costs into that problem.

So before jumping onto the engineering task, make sure that the benefit will justify the costs. Maybe check on these alternative approaches first:

1. Don't do it. Only update on a user interaction. Maybe add a reload button.
2. Only notify the user that an update occurred, but only update when the user hits "reload". This solves the problem that the user may not have the browser tab in focus and the transfer is a waste.

> But I am concerning the memory usage that this will create in case I have a lot of users and the user list with the item ids can be very big too.

In our applications we observe that there are not so many different search patterns / filters. Let's say you might have 1000 user sessions, but only 20 different popular searches. If that is true, you can do:

- For each search filter, you can store a hash value of the result.
- If you do the update of the main data, you run the searches again and only send an update to the user if the hash value changed.

If it is a public web application, you should optimize more. E.g. don't send an update when the application has no focus.